# JAPE check for numeric only input

Tags: nlp, gate, named-entity-recognition

I have the below JAPE file  for ANNIE in which I am trying to ensure that establishments names which contain only numeric characters do not get annotated.

I have tried many variations of the below but do not seem to be able to get it to work.

```
Phase:Establishment
Input: Lookup Token
Options: control = appelt

Rule: EstablishmentNonNumeric
Priority: 100
//do not tag establishment names which contain only numbers as this is just weird
(
({Lookup.majorType == "establishment", Lookup.kind == number})
): temp
-->
{ }

Rule: Establishment
(
{Lookup.majorType == "establishment"}
): temp
-->
:temp.Establishment ={rule= "EstablishmentRule" }
```

I have a feeling it may be to do with the control setting but I am not really sure.

Many thanks!

Comment: If my answer don't solve your problem, please add more info: post/describe an **example** document and the intended result: what should and what should not be annotated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you meant:

```
Token.kind == number
```

instead of:

```
Lookup.kind == number
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you